# workbook cannot be opened when trying to integrate office web app in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, office365, ms-wopi

I have been following this [tutorial](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Building-an-Office-Web-f98650d6/view/Discussions)  to open office web apps online but when I click URL generated by selecting the excel file I get error

> workbook cannot be opened

you may test [here](http://5.56.58.107/) to check the issues

Discovery.xml file is taken from [HERE](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_test_ship/environments.html) production environment and code is hosted on my own server

Comment: kindly help need this urgently

Answer (score 0):

You can't just take the discovery file from the [WOPI docs](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_test_ship/environments.html#wopi-discovery-urls). As the docs say:

> These URLs are publicly accessible. However, you will not be able to invoke any WOPI actions successfully unless your WOPI domain has been added to the WOPI domain allow list.

The discovery file contains URLs to a working WOPI client instance. This needs to be either Office Online with your domain added to white-list or an on-premise instance of the Office Online Server. [Here's](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost#compatible-wopi-clients) how to install it locally. Then, fetch the discovery file from your instance.